# Is it possible to implement Stopwords without Elasticsearch configured in magento 2.3 + How to implement stopwords in magento 2.3

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2, stop-words, magento-2.3, elasticsearch-6

I want to add stopwords to my project but I think Elasticsearch is not installed on my server. Search Engine as MYSQL is selected.

will our stopwords work or not without Elasticsearch configured?

Also, I want to make sure that elastic search is configured or not. For that I am using the command

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

and in response, I am getting output as:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost:9200; Connection refused.

Does this signify that elastic search is not configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the proper solution to this question.

a) Install Elasticsearch6.0

b) Then follow the steps https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-config-stopwords.html#to-change-directory-stopwords

But one thing that needs to be kept in the mind is:
Don't override the stopwords.csv file
Instead, override the stopwords_en_US.csv file i.e. according to your locale.

Your module will work perfectly.
The solution on all sites is perfect. Just we need to override the correct file for stopwords according to locale.